# I'm getting different user data after Login

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I am working on an app that user needs to login requiring username and password that I have stored in database and after logging in I will be able to see the information of the account entered but I'm getting different data of other account

Login class

```
public class DocLogin extends Fragment {

ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvItemName, tvRegister;
EditText user, pass;
Button btnLogin;
String username, password;
SQLController dbcon;
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
Editor editor;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


public DocLogin() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_log_in, container, false);

    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    // Log in
    user = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // Sign up
    tvRegister = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegDoc);
    tvRegister.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tvRegister.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocReg());
            ft.commit();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // btnLogin onClickListener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            user.setSelection(user.length());

            username = user.getText().toString();
            password = pass.getText().toString();
            sharedPreferences();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful", 20).show();

            Log.d("DocLogin", user.getText().toString());
            Log.v("LoginDetails", user.getText().toString() + "../.."
                    + pass.getText().toString());
            Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
                Cursor c = dbcon.getUserData();

                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                DocProfile fragment = new DocProfile();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("RegId", c.getString(1));
                bundle.putString("DocCode", c.getString(2));
                bundle.putString("Firstname", c.getString(3));
                bundle.putString("Lastname", c.getString(4));
                bundle.putString("Specialty", c.getString(5));
                bundle.putString("CardId", c.getString(6));
                bundle.putString("Region", c.getString(7));
                bundle.putString("Location", c.getString(8));
                bundle.putString("Contact", c.getString(9));
                bundle.putString("Monday", c.getString(10));
                bundle.putString("Tuesday", c.getString(11));
                bundle.putString("Wednesday", c.getString(12));
                bundle.putString("Thursday", c.getString(13));
                bundle.putString("Friday", c.getString(14));
                bundle.putString("Saturday", c.getString(15));
                bundle.putString("Sunday", c.getString(16));
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            } else {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // dismiss dialog
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void sharedPreferences() {

    sh_Pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = sh_Pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString("Username", username);
    editor.putString("Password", password);
    editor.commit();
  }

}
```

Profile class

```
public class DocProfile extends Fragment {

SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
SessionManager session;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLController dbcon;
Cursor cursor;
SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

public DocProfile() {

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_profile, container, false);


    TextView fname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.docFirstname);
    TextView lname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.docLastname);
    TextView spec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_spec);
    TextView loc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_location);
    TextView con = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_contact);

    String regid = "", doccode = "", first = "", last = "", specialty = "", location = "", contact = "";

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("RegId"))
        regid = args.getString("RegId");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("DocCode"))
        doccode = args.getString("DocCode");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Firstname"))
        first = args.getString("Firstname");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Lastname"))
        last = args.getString("Lastname");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Specialty"))
        specialty = args.getString("Specialty");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Location"))
        location = args.getString("Location");

    if (args != null && args.containsKey("Contact"))
        contact = args.getString("Contact");

    fname.setText(first);
    lname.setText(last);
    spec.setText(specialty);
    loc.setText(location);
    con.setText(contact);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logout, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout:
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREF", PRIVATE_MODE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocLogin());
        ft.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logout Successful", 20).show();
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }

}
```

DB class

```
public class SQLController {

private SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new SqlDbHelper(context);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void insertData(String regid, String doc_code, String firstname,
        String lastname, String specialty, String card_id, String region,
        String location, String contact, String monday, String tuesday,
        String wednesday, String thursday, String friday, String saturday,
        String sunday, String pass, String conpass) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, regid);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE, doc_code);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, firstname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, lastname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, specialty);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID, card_id);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, region);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, location);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, contact);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_MON, monday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_TUE, tuesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_WED, wednesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_THU, thursday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_FRI, friday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SAT, saturday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SUN, sunday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONPASS, conpass);
    database.insert(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}


public Cursor getUserData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { SqlDbHelper._id,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_MON,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_TUE, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_WED,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_THU, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_FRI,
            SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SAT, SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SUN,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS, SqlDbHelper.COL_CONPASS, };
    Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public Cursor getuser_information(String docid, String password) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(true, SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID,
                    SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE, SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS },
            SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE + "='"
                    + docid.toString().toLowerCase() + "' and "
                    + SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS + "='" + password + "'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    } else
        return cursor;

    }

}


public class SqlDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "doc_table";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "doc_db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String _id = "_id";
public static final String COL_REG_ID = "reg_id";
public static final String COL_DOC_CODE = "doc_code";
public static final String COL_FNAME = "firstname";
public static final String COL_LNAME = "lastname";
public static final String COL_SPEC = "specialty";
public static final String COL_CARD_ID = "card_id";
public static final String COL_REGION = "region";
public static final String COL_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String COL_CONTACT = "contact";
public static final String SCHED_MON = "monday";
public static final String SCHED_TUE = "tuesday";
public static final String SCHED_WED = "wednesday";
public static final String SCHED_THU = "thursday";
public static final String SCHED_FRI = "friday";
public static final String SCHED_SAT = "saturday";
public static final String SCHED_SUN = "sunday";
public static final String COL_PASS = "password";
public static final String COL_CONPASS = "confirm_password";
private static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + _id
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_REG_ID
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_DOC_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_SPEC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CARD_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_REGION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_LOCATION
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_MON
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_TUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_WED
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_THU + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_FRI
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + SCHED_SUN
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CONPASS
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public SqlDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you do this:

`Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
                Cursor c = dbcon.getUserData();`

and get the information fron the c cursor instead of the cur cursor you are getting another information because in dbcon.getUserData you are doing a different query than the bdcon.getuser_information that does the query with the user login info.

So I think you should use the cur cursor for getting the info of the user.

Sorry for my English. I hope this helps.